# Extract file from ext4 image and copy file to device

Tags: ext4, dd, embedded, images

[Here](https://www.emcraft.com/som/stm32mp1/booting-linux-from-emmc) I read:

```
$ cd /media/mmcblk1p2
$ tar xf /media/sda1/mfg_images/st-image-bootfs-openstlinux-weston-stm32mp1-som.tar.xz
```

but as source file I don't have a compressed file, instead I have an `ext4` image for that partition. Should I use `dd` with `of=/dev/mmcblk1p2` or I need to use another approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mount the filesystem image directly into your filesystem:

```
mkdir -p /mnt/img
mount -o ro,noload imagefile.img /mnt/img
```

and then you can retrieve the file directly from the appropriate place underneath `/mnt/img`. (The `ro,noload` options mount the filesystem read-only. Omit them both if you want read/write access.)

Unmount the file afterwards with

```
umount /mnt/img
```